# Removed custom extension but Magento throwing error

Tags: extensions

I am trying to access the admin area of my magento installation after deleting my custom extension. I have removed all the files for my extension. I have also removed all database entries for it. Including core_config and core_resource. I have removed the etc/modules extension file.

However I still get this error when trying to log in to admin area.

```
Warning: include(Cti/Enhancedform/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /vagrant/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

Any help is appreciated. I am trying to simulate the extension being installed from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something is still referencing this extension:

- Template code manually calling `Mage::helper('enhancedform')` or simliar
- A portion of the module used in admin translation for the admin panel that is left behind. Maybe you missed the admin module code in `app/design/adminhtml`?

Hope that helps!

Comment: That worked :) Thank you. However please see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82504/extension-no-longer-exists-why-am-i-able-to-disable-it-in-the-advanced-area-in