# Extension no longer exists. Why am I able to disable it in the Advanced area in Admin?

Tags: extensions

I have removed all records of my extension from the  file system and also the database. However, I am still able to enable or disable the output of it in the admin area.

How can I remove the option from 'Disable Module Output'?

I am trying to simulate what would happen on initial install of the extension.

Answer (score 3):

Because the module registration XML still exists. Check app/etc/modules for an XML that references your removed module.

Comment: There is no reference to the module. :(

Comment: I have also cleared all cache and session files. Compiler is not turned on. And caching is turned off.